# Валидация в инпуте react

Tags: html, reactjs, input, валидация

Всем привет, у меня есть 2 инпута

```
<Input placeholder="ИНН1" validate={isValidate}/>
<Input placeholder="ИНН2" validate={isValidate}/>
```

и одинаковая функция валидации для них

```
export const isValidate = value =>
  value && value.match(/^(\d{10}|\d{12})$/) ? undefined : 'Error';
```

как сюда можно добавить условие , что если ИНН1 = ИНН2 то возвращать error, может как-то создать для них разные функции ( если что это функция валидации находится в другом файле)

Comment: У стандартного инпута нет свойства validate. Вы какой-то библиотекой пользуетесь?

Comment: я не понял .То есть если у первого инпута в value написали ИНН1 а во втором ИНН2 то проста сбросить ошибку?Все правильно?